# WPF UI not responsive in spite of process running in a seperate thread. Why?

Tags: c#, wpf

Using threading in WPF makes no difference for me. The UI continues to be not responsive.

This is my code:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(LoadImages));
    th.Start();
}

void LoadImages()
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker(delegate() {
        IService1 svc = ConnectAndGetObject();
        foreach (byte[] imgbytes in svc.GetImageDateWise(datePicker1.DisplayDate, DateTime.Now, "test"))
        {
            using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(imgbytes))
            {
                BitmapImage jpgimage = new BitmapImage();
                jpgimage.BeginInit();

                jpgimage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;

                jpgimage.StreamSource = mem;

                jpgimage.EndInit();

                //  PngBitmapDecoder decodejpg = new PngBitmapDecoder(mem, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnDemand);
                Image wpfimage = new Image();
                wpfimage.Source = jpgimage.Clone();

                lbx.Items.Add(wpfimage);
                lbx.UpdateLayout();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }));
}
```

**Updated working code:**

```
      List<MemoryStream> mems = new List<MemoryStream>();
        void LoadImages()
        {

            IService1 svc = ConnectAndGetObject();
            foreach (byte[] imgbytes in svc.GetImageDateWise(GetDate(), DateTime.Now, "test"))
            {
   this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate() {
       mems.Add(new MemoryStream(imgbytes));


                    BitmapImage jpgimage = new BitmapImage();
                    jpgimage.BeginInit();

                    jpgimage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.None;

                    jpgimage.StreamSource = mems[mems.Count-1];

                    jpgimage.EndInit();

                  Image wpfimage = new Image();
                  wpfimage.Source = jpgimage.Clone();
                    lbx.Items.Add(wpfimage);
                    lbx.UpdateLayout();
                    Thread.Sleep(500);


   }));
            }
            mems.Clear();


        }
```

Comment: Not to bash on Josh, but this is one of those clear examples from the school of Just-Throw-Some-Threads-Or-Cores-At-It-And-It-Will-Be-Faster.

Comment: thats right Fernandes...i didn't know that everything inside the method invoker would run on the UI thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code the *entire* body of `LoadImages` is Invoked right back to the main thread. So you do not have a multi-threaded solution at all, just a complicated one.

Here is my stab at it:

```
// untested
void LoadImages()
{
       // this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
       //    new System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker(delegate() {
    IService1 svc = ConnectAndGetObject();
    foreach (byte[] imgbytes in svc.GetImageDateWise(datePicker1.DisplayDate, DateTime.Now, "test"))
    {   
        using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(imgbytes))
        {    
            BitmapImage jpgimage = new BitmapImage();
            jpgimage.BeginInit();    
            jpgimage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;    
            jpgimage.StreamSource = mem;    
            jpgimage.EndInit();

            // only invoke the part actually touching the UI    
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
              new System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker(delegate() {
                  Image wpfimage = new Image();
                  wpfimage.Source = jpgimage; //.Clone();
                  lbx.Items.Add(wpfimage);
                  lbx.UpdateLayout();   } ));

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }    
   //  }));
}
```

Comment: If I use the code you have provided,I'm getting this exception "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this." on the line "Image wpfimage = new Image();"

Comment: You can move those 2 lines inside the Invoke part. And I don't think you need the Clone() call.

Comment: If I move it in,it throws this at me "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."...It does not point to any line on the IDE...IDE shows a message "No Symbols are loaded for any call stack frame.The source code cannot be displayed"

Comment: It might be the BitmapCacheOption, I'll look it up.

Comment: tried changing the BitmapCacheOption to none...still getting the same error. My code looks exactly like that...here's the same pasted from my VS IDE...     this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker(delegate() {
                  Image wpfimage = new Image();
                  wpfimage.Source = jpgimage.Clone();
                    lbx.Items.Add(wpfimage);
                    lbx.UpdateLayout();
                   }));

Comment: OK, note that I put the BeginInit/EndInit back, my mistake.

Comment: no Henk,actually I had to start the dispatcher the very next line after the loop and end it when the loop ends. Apart from that,it expected me not to dispose the memory stream for some reason...and now it works after I changed that.I really have no idea why the error actually came though

Comment: But Thank You Henk...You tried a great deal to help me...I've posted the code that actually worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the first thing your non UI thread does is invoke a delegate on the UI thread. The net result is a lot of overhead with no cocurrency at all.

Reorg your code so that only UI tasks are done on the UI thread.

```
void LoadImages() 
{ 
    IService1 svc = ConnectAndGetObject(); 
...
Dispatcher.Invoke( () => lbx.Items.Add(wpfimage));
....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing too much in your delegate. This might be the cause of your problems, plus the 1 second sleep you have in there.

Just have the code that updates the list box in the delegate:

```
        lbx.Items.Add(wpfimage);
        lbx.UpdateLayout();
```

Failing that raise an event in your thread and subscribe to it in your main application and update the UI from that.

You'll need a method along these lines:

```
    private void ImageAdded_EventHandler(object sender, ImageAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        Action action = () => ImageAdded(e.Image);
        if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            action();
        }
        else
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, action);
        }
    }
```

Where `ImageAddedEventArgs` is a class based on `EventArgs` that has a property of the image data.

Comment: or use the WPF `Dispatcher`: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher

Comment: I tried removing the Thread.sleep and the lbx.updatelayout stuff.....Now,the listbox doesnt get updated immediately...but the Application still continues to get stuck  for a few seconds when I click the button until the process is over.

Comment: @Josh - see Henk Holterman's answer. I missed that your entire method was inside a delegate.

Comment: yeah,checked that...but please see my comment there..I'm getting a new exception if i do that.